# My animation is lagging, why?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have an animation in unity, and basically it shows Donald Trump running:

[image]

I also have this one frame animation of Trump jumping:

[image]

Basically, when he jumps, the jump animation plays, and when he lands, the walk animation plays again.

[image]

This all works, and this code runs it:

```
function Update() {
    trump.velocity = Vector2(speed, trump.velocity.y);
    if (jump > 0) {
        jumpBool = true;
    }
    else {
        jumpBool = false;
    }
    animator.SetBool("Jump", jumpBool);
```

That's in the physics script. Then from the animator:

[image]
[image]

This all works, and the animations change when they are supposed to. The issue is, it lags before it finishes. I think that when Trump jumps, the walk animation finishes before it switches to the jump animation. My question is, how do I automatically switch animations immediately, so it won't look so laggy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can immediately call the Jump animation to be played at the point you make the JumpBool = true. Doing so you don't need to wait for the walk animation finish, it will simply stop the Walk and and move to Jump.

```
function Update() {
    trump.velocity = Vector2(speed, trump.velocity.y);
    if (jump > 0) {
        animator.Play("Trump Jump");
        //jumpBool = true;
    }
    else {
        //jumpBool = false;
    }
    //animator.SetBool("Jump", jumpBool);
```

[image]

You don't even need to Set the bool, after the Jump animation has finished it will move back to the Walk animation.

[image]